# Chart.js 2.0 doughnut tooltip percentages

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I have worked with chart.js 1.0 and had my doughnut chart tooltips displaying percentages based on data divided by dataset, but I'm unable to replicate this with chart 2.0.

I have searched high and low and have not found a working solution. I know that it will go under options but everything I've tried has made the pie dysfunctional at best.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Doughnut Chart</title>
    <script src="../dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    canvas {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="canvas-holder" style="width:75%">
        <canvas id="chart-area" />
    </div>
    <script>
    var randomScalingFactor = function() {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    };
    var randomColorFactor = function() {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    };
    var randomColor = function(opacity) {
        return 'rgba(' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + (opacity || '.3') + ')';
    };

    var config = {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [
                    486.5,
                    501.5,
                    139.3,
                    162,
                    263.7,
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#F7464A",
                    "#46BFBD",
                    "#FDB45C",
                    "#949FB1",
                    "#4D5360",
                ],
                label: 'Expenditures'
            }],
            labels: [
                "Hospitals: $486.5 billion",
                "Physicians & Professional Services: $501.5 billion",
                "Long Term Care: $139.3 billion",
                "Prescription Drugs: $162 billion",
                "Other Expenditures: $263.7 billion"
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
                position: 'bottom',
            },
            title: {
                display: false,
                text: 'Chart.js Doughnut Chart'
            },
            animation: {
                animateScale: true,
                animateRotate: true
            }

        }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
        window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);{

        }
    };


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

**Update:** The below answer shows a percentage based on total data but `@William Surya Permana` has an excellent answer that updates based on the shown data https://stackoverflow.com/a/49717859/2737978

---

In `options` you can pass in a `tooltips` object (more can be read at the [chartjs docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration))

A field of `tooltips`, to get the result you want, is a `callbacks` object with a `label` field. `label` will be a function that takes in the tooltip item which you have hovered over and the data which makes up your graph. Just return a string, that you want to go in the tooltip, from this function.

Here is an example of what this can look like

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      //get the concerned dataset
      var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
      //calculate the total of this data set
      var total = dataset.data.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
        return previousValue + currentValue;
      });
      //get the current items value
      var currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
      //calculate the precentage based on the total and current item, also this does a rough rounding to give a whole number
      var percentage = Math.floor(((currentValue/total) * 100)+0.5);

      return percentage + "%";
    }
  }
}
```

and a full example with the data you provided

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/q4yaa78c/)

```js
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
};
var randomColorFactor = function() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
};
var randomColor = function(opacity) {
  return 'rgba(' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + (opacity || '.3') + ')';
};

var config = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [
        486.5,
        501.5,
        139.3,
        162,
        263.7,
      ],
      backgroundColor: [
        "#F7464A",
        "#46BFBD",
        "#FDB45C",
        "#949FB1",
        "#4D5360",
      ],
      label: 'Expenditures'
    }],
    labels: [
      "Hospitals: $486.5 billion",
      "Physicians & Professional Services: $501.5 billion",
      "Long Term Care: $139.3 billion",
      "Prescription Drugs: $162 billion",
      "Other Expenditures: $263.7 billion"
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
    },
    title: {
      display: false,
      text: 'Chart.js Doughnut Chart'
    },
    animation: {
      animateScale: true,
      animateRotate: true
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
         var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
          var total = dataset.data.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
            return previousValue + currentValue;
          });
          var currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
          var percentage = Math.floor(((currentValue/total) * 100)+0.5);         
          return percentage + "%";
        }
      }
    }
  }
};


var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config); {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas-holder" style="width:75%">
  <canvas id="chart-area" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can we show the percentage dynamically in the legend text?

Comment: If every answers were like this one... Good job dude

Comment: This is not working when you hide/scratch labels. Is there a way you can calculate the % based on the not-scratched labels?

Comment: parseInt the previousValue and curentValue for assurance.

Comment: Thank you! I extended your example to include the item text with `return data.labels[tooltipItem.datasetIndex] + ": " + percentage + "%"`

Comment: What if we want that number too along with `%`

Comment: For those of you in 2022 where that doesn't work try writing "tooltip" instead of "tooltips"

Answer (score 73):

For those who want to display dynamic percentages based on what currently displayed on the chart (not based on total data), you can try this code:

```
 tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
        var meta = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]];
        var total = meta.total;
        var currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
        var percentage = parseFloat((currentValue/total*100).toFixed(1));
        return currentValue + ' (' + percentage + '%)';
      },
      title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: I prefer this one because
1. I also need the tooltip titles
2. `percentage` is spelled right

Comment: Thank's this works even better than accepted answer ( although it's excellent due to merit input :) )

Comment: *takes hat off*

Comment: For those of us using Chart.js via ChartKick with Rails (or any other API wrapper), you can't set _functions_ to those options above (because they'll just render as strings, not callable functions).
However you can simply access the chart on the client side after the page loads and override the label and title functions there by accessing `Chartkick.charts['<your_chart_id>'].getChartObject().tooltip._options.callbacks`. `label` and `title` are sub-attributes that can be set from there.

Comment: Simple and easy

Answer (score 12):

In 3.5 it will be:

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(context){
          var data = context.dataset.data,
              label = context.label,
              currentValue = context.raw,
              total = 0;

          for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
            total += data[i];
          }
          var percentage = parseFloat((currentValue/total*100).toFixed(1));

          return label + ": " +currentValue + ' (' + percentage + '%)';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but better, dynamic version:

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(context){
          var label = context.label,
              currentValue = context.raw,
              total = context.chart._metasets[context.datasetIndex].total;

          var percentage = parseFloat((currentValue/total*100).toFixed(1));

          return label + ": " +currentValue + ' (' + percentage + '%)';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer worked for me (Chart.js v3.7.0). Thank a lot @unbreak

Comment: Much thanks man, this is the only answer that worked for me. All others didn't.

Comment: Works fine with 3.9.1

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question because I needed to show percentage on stacked bar charts. The percentage I needed was per stacked columns. I accomplished this by modifying Willian Surya's answer like this:

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      var index = tooltipItem.index;
      var currentValue = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[index];
      var total = 0;
      data.datasets.forEach(function(el){
        total = total + el.data[index];
      });
      var percentage = parseFloat((currentValue/total*100).toFixed(1));
      return currentValue + ' (' + percentage + '%)';
    },
    title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      return data.datasets[tooltipItem[0].datasetIndex].label;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the final result:

[image: ChartJS Percentage for stacked bar charts]

Comment: is it possible that the data on the Y axis has "%" too?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this:

```
const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
        tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
                label: (Item) => '%' + (Item.formattedValue) + ' | ' + Item.label
            }
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage has changed in 3.x and higher versions, so I will attach a method for this.

```
const data: ChartData = {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: excerciseData,
            backgroundColor: [
                "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)",
                "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)",
                "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.5)",
                "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.5)",
                "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5)",
                "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.5)"
            ]
        }
    ]
};
...

     callbacks: {
                    label: tooltipItem => {
                        let total = 0;
                        data.datasets[0].data.forEach(num => {
                            total += num as number;
                        });
                        const currentValue = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.dataIndex] as number;

                        const percentage = ((currentValue * 100) / total).toFixed(1) + "%";

                        return `${currentValue}(${percentage})`;
                    },
                    title: tooltipItems => {
                        return tooltipItems[0].label;
                    }
                }
```