# Chartkick: how to specify tooltip labels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, chartkick

I use [Chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) Ruby library to create some pie charts. I want the chart to show some specific text on each part of the pie tooltips but the library show its value instead. I managed to specify colors for parts like this:

```
<%= pie_chart {First: 1, Second: 2, Third: 3}, colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue']>
```

But I don't want the chart show values on tooltips (now it is showing 1, 2 and 3 accordingly), I need it to display some strings like "One, "Two", "Three". I was trying all three JS libraries (ChartJS, Google Charts, Highcharts) but with no luck.
How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this issue in [chartkick github repo](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js/issues/85) this is not supported in chartkick as of now but he might add this in future

> Hey @dominicsanto, this isn't possible right now, but on the top of my list of desired features.

But this is possible in native chartjs you can easily do it using callback see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257034/chart-js-2-0-doughnut-tooltip-percentages) for detailed answer